# How to implement "Skip to content" accessibility functionality on React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accessibility

When we are using keyboard only and tab through the website, the first anchor link for "Skip to a content" is shown to skip the navigation and focus to the main content which makes the web page accessible. It is easy to add such a feature on multi-page website where there is full page reload and the focus for the page resets. I am looking similar behavior on the React. How can we implement such behavior on a Single page application built on React?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I created a div with a reference and focused the reference on componentDidMount lifecycle. I was able to click on the route link and jump into the main content. However, i wanted a behavior to be more like resetting the page focus to the top of the page, so that I will be able to implement the "Skip to a content" to jump into the related link content.

Comment: full page reload for 'skip to main content' sounds like a really bad plan

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with Graham that you shouldn't need a skip to content link. In a SPA, when the user navigates to a new "page," the focus remains on the link that was pressed. Every time your user wants to navigate, they're going to have to go through the remaining nav menu to get at the content.

You could either move focus to the beginning of the document so they hit your 'skip to content' link each time (has its merits because it's most like multi-page apps which they're likely to be familiar with) or move it to the content body itself and save them a click (seems more streamlined to me, but might be unfamiliar to your users).

```
    componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout(() => document.getElementById('your-element-of-choice').focus(), 0)
    }
```

I'm leaning toward the latter, but this will work either way you decide to implement it. Don't forget to set the tab index on the element you want to focus on to -1 as well.

Comment: Re-read what I wrote, I clearly state moving the focus to the new region that has been updated, which is the accepted pattern for SPA navigation and exactly what you suggested here. Additionally I never said to remove the skip to content link, just that it wasn't applicable to this use case and is only applicable to return visitors / initial page load.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't need a skip to content link on a SPA other than the one you already have (for first time load for return visitors).

Skip to content is for when you click a link to a new page, it helps avoid having to listen to the menu every time you navigate.

With a SPA that isn't an issue as everything is done via AJAX, when I click a link a region on the page will get updated with new content.

All you need to do is move focus to the region that is being updated from the menu item.

Certain screen readers will need explicit [ARIA Live Regions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Live_Regions) in order to register the new content so make sure you test it with a screen reader.

Where you will run into accessibility problems pretty fast in SPAs are when you start thinking about delays.

What happens if I click that link and the page takes 3 seconds to load?

What happens if the page doesn't load at all?

Those are your bigger challenges with a SPA.